# LinkColum with urlencode()

Tags: django, django-tables2

I have a `LinkColum`  like this:

```
artist = tables.LinkColumn('artist_detail', args=[A('artist')],
```

Unfortunately, there are artists which have special characters like a slash in it and are breaking the Django-URL-system.

```
Reverse for 'artist_detail' with arguments '('Paul Ray Featuring 33 1/3',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['artists\\/(?P<artist>[^/]+)$']
```

I tried to encapsulate `A('artist')` with `django.utils.http.urlencode()` but that's not working unfortunately.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#column) you should be using a normal column and using the `linkify` parameter.

```
artist = tables.Column(linkify=("artist_detail", (tables.A("artist.pk"), )))
```

Comment: I must admit that I overlooked `linkify` in the docs.
Unfortunately it results in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

django-tables2 is just relaying these to django's `django.urls.reverse`. There is no url matching the value you've passed, so you would have to adjust the value you pass.

One way to achieve this is to add a method to your model providing the `urlencode`d version of the name, and specify that method in the accessor.

Alternatively you can implement a `get_absolute_url` method on your model and do the `urlencode`ing in there. You can then use

```
 artist = tables.Column(linkify=true)
```

I prefer the latter.